# How can I configure my company mail (Outlook Web App) in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange-2010

My company has changed mail server to Outlook Web App (OWA). Is there any way to configure my mail in Microsoft Outlook 2007? I used Outlook for the new email address from Outlook Web App, but Outlook 2007 error and doesn't allow the emails to come over to outlook 2007. I want to use offline my email.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the solely allow OWA then you are screwed :(

Ask the ICT department if they offer acces to their exchange/imap/pop server. You need one of these to be able to configure your email account in Outlook/Thunderbird/your smartphone/etc.

Comment: They said "Outlook Web App doesn't support IMAP or POP". What do you think?

Comment: I think you will not be able to read your mail offline. I have seen other companies also changing from imap support to strictly owa. I reslly dislike this approach. It is supposed to be safer (when you lose uour phone / lsptop nobody can read the emsil with owa, compated to an imap configered email client). The companies don't care for a moment about convenience. It is really sad.